# Different behavior between Neo Console and older web User Interface (running 2.1.3)

Tags: neo4j

Well, I just started neo:, 2.1.3 on a Ubuntu machine:

```
 pdipietro@CUC-N4J-V4-0-0:~/gsn$ rake neo4j:start
 Starting Neo4j development...
 pdipietro@CUC-N4J-V4-0-0:~/gsn$
```

Now, if I open it in the browsed I got the following error:

[image]

But if I click the webadmin in the classicUI it start correctly

[image]

and run, with the expected results.

[image]

Tis is the config and there are plenty of GB of mmory.
[image]

Any Idea?

Thank you in advance

Paolo

Thank you for bot suggestions, but I'm not able to resolve:

```
http://localhost:7474/browser is disconnected from Neo4j, while
http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/ runs fine
```

I wasn't able to discover any evident config flaw.

Where are the two different config files?

Comment: When you run the shell, you're not showing us which DB you're connecting to.  How is your webadmin configured?  Is that connecting to the same directory database as your shell?

Comment: Perhaps there is a network issue, please check your browser developer tools for the network operations if there are any issues.